# Python script exporting environment variables but printenv http_proxy doesn't return anything

Tags: python

I've written a Python script to export http_proxy environment variables:

```
import os
proxy = "http://proxy:port"
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
```

But `printenv http_proxy` doesn't return anything in terminal.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  [ask] Where are you expecting to set the proxy values? What results do you expect this code to generate? **The environment variable will be set only for the current session of the Python interpreter.** https://www.askpython.com/python/environment-variables-in-python If you document your research, that will avoid people voting to close questions for lack of research reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Python (which will not work because environment can only be inherited to child processes, not back to parent processes) you can set the variables directly in the init file of your respective shell.

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy:port'
export HTTP_PROXY="${http_proxy}"
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I want to set a system wide proxy settings on my machine using python. I don't want to use the export http_proxy command.

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane so you want to change the proxy settings in System Preferences from Python? It needs more than setting an env variable for this. Please edit the question to explain your goal in more details.

Comment: No, I want to set system wide proxy settings without using the environment variables. The export http_proxy doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane Which system wide proxy settings are you referring to?

Comment: I am using a MacOS Big Sur

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane If you are referring to the proxy settings usually defined within System Preferences, the `networksetup` command might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does it use the environment variables?

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane no

Comment: Can you please write the command line for Wi-FI? Host: 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane `man networksetup` should give you all the details you need to find out how to do this. If it doesn't work, please ask a new question describing what you want to accomplish, what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This is the new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657619/how-to-set-system-wide-http-proxy-settings-on-macos

Comment: @AnassRhouzlane Isn't that the same question as asked here? Also, I fail to see how any of the feedback you recived helped you in improving your approach on solving the problem.